# OS X Lion Inverted Scrolling Automation Shortcut

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-lion, automator

As everyone will know (who has Mac OS X Lion), by default, scrolling is inverted to make it a bit like the iPhone.

Problem: There is no way to have "normal scrolling" for a USB mouse, and "natural/inverted" scrolling for the trackpad. The setting (even though it is listed in both the mouse and trackpad settings) applies to both.

Question: Could someone, who is experienced with Automator or AppleScipting, please give me a few tips on how to make a shortcut that can toggle the inverted setting? I need this as when I'm at home, I have my Mac Book Air plugged to my Keyboard, Mouse and Monitor, and I'd like a quick way to change this setting

Comment: Just curious, is opening Preferences not fast enough?

Comment: I'm constantly docking and undocking my mac book, so a nice shortcut to change this would be nice.

Comment: Why are people voting down this post? Is there something I have done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to set the current pane to "com.apple.preference.mouse"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click radio button "Point & Click" of tab group 1 of window "Mouse"
        click the first checkbox
    end tell
end tell
```

**Final Working Solution:**

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.trackpad"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click radio button "Scroll & Zoom" of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
        click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences"
    quit
end tell
```

Comment: This is what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/L0Tf7NSh It says it can't find checkbox 1

Comment: `...checkbox of group 1` try that.

Comment: "System Events got an error: Can’t get group 1 of process "System Preferences". Invalid index."

Comment: Ok, this works: http://pastebin.com/JGUvA8U9 Any ideas on how I get the window to close?

Comment: Ok: this is my final solution: http://pastebin.com/67PH15Ee

Comment: In case anyone else would try this out, the value isn't updated immediately when modifying `.GlobalPreferences` directly. `k=com.apple.swipescrolldirection; r=\`defaults read -g $k\`; [[ $r == "1" ]] && b=false || b=true; echo $b; defaults write -g $k -bool $b`

Comment: This is not working for me for Mac OS 10.9.5